# Need help using range for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am making a program that calculates the sum of all even and odd numbers between two number which are user inputted. I'm new to Python and am not sure how to use the `range` in a loop to make my program work. Here is my code. I know its sloppy and not well put together and not finished but any help works thanks.

```
n = int(input(" please enter a number"))
m= int(input(" please enter another number"))
count =0
sum =0
for x in range(n,m+1,2):
    if x%2==0:
        count=count+x
    sum = count
    print(" the total sum of odd numbers are",sum)
```

Comment: you are not testing if I input odd or even numbers. Your range only takes every 2nd number so the x%2 == 0 test is not needed - you only ever have odd OR even numbers depending on what you start with.  Dont use `sum` as variable name, there is already a built in function called `sum` - you are shadowing it. If you want to sum values you can do :  `print(sum( range( 10,21,2) ) )` and get the result of  10+12+14+16+18+20

Comment: `calculates the sum of all even and odd numbers between two number `: Does it means you do 2 sums, one for even numbers and other for odd numbers?

Comment: @emi yes i am calculating 2 sums

Answer (score 1):

It's important to know if `n` is greater than `m` and invert situation if so. Other than that, you need to know if the smallest number is odd or even and begin the two ranges accordingly:

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
m = int(input("Please enter another number: "))

# n will always be the smaller one
if n > m:
    n, m = m, n

n_is_odd = n % 2 # Gives 1 if n is odd

n_even = n + n_is_odd # Sum 1 if n is odd
n_odd = n + (not n_is_odd) # Sum 1 if n is even

print("the total sum of even numbers is %d" % sum(range(n_even, m+1, 2)) )
print("the total sum of odd numbers is %d" % sum(range(n_odd, m+1, 2)) )
```

Comment: confused on what tmp is

Comment: A temporal variable to swap `n` and `m` values. Fixed with list assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Input validation is a big part of good coding. A good overview can be found here:

- [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

To make the validation it reusable I put the validation in a function that only accept integers and (if a `minval` is provided, makes sure that the input is bigger that the minval.

```
def while_invalid_ask_input_return_integer(text, minval = None):
    """Aks for input until a number is given that is > minval if minval not None
    returns an integer."""
    while True:
        c = input (text)
        try:
            c = int(c)
            if minval is not None and c < minval:
                raise ValueError  # its too small, raise an erros so we jump to except:
            return c
        except ValueError:
            if minval is not None:
                print("must be a number and greater ", minval)
            else:
                print("not a number")
```

I use it to get the first number, and the second number gets the first one as "constraint" so it will be bigger. For summation I just use the range starting once with `n` once with `n+1` till m and a range `step` of 2. I check what even/oddness `n` has and print text accordingly:

```
n = while_invalid_ask_input_return_integer("please enter a number ")
m = while_invalid_ask_input_return_integer("enter number bigger then {}".format(n),n)

print( "Odd sum:" if n % 2 == 1 else "Even sum:", sum(range(n,m+1,2)) )
print( "Even sum:" if n % 2 == 1 else "Odd sum:", sum(range(n+1,m+1,2)) )
```

Output:

```
please enter a number k
not a number
please enter a number 55
enter number bigger then 55 2
must be a number and greater  55
enter number bigger then 55 150
Odd sum: 4896
Even sum: 4944
```

Doku:

- [sum(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)
- [try: except: error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)
- [python ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) (thats the thing @ `"Odd sum:" if n % 2 == 1 else "Even sum:"` in the print statement)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I think fits into the description of what you asked above. It returns `None` if the user doesn't enter the type of query he or she wants.

So query can either be `odd` or `even` and depending on this, it calculates the sum that you want. The function makes use of list comprehension which is super cool too.

```
def calculate_odd_or_even_sum(query):
    start = int(input(" please enter a number"))
    end = int(input(" please enter another number"))
    count = 0

    if query == 'even':
        return sum([x for x in range(start, end) if x % 2 == 0])
    elif query == 'odd':
        return sum([x for x in range(start, end) if x % 2 != 0])
    else:
        return 0
```